# Drupal PHP Content Warns of Virus

Tags: php, javascript, forms, drupal, virus

I have a Drupal site with a page that contains a PHP form. The php form connects to a database and posts the content there and it also has some javascript statements.

The problems:

- If I edit the drupal node and copy out the PHP and try to save to a document on my computer it warns of a virus.
- If I open to edit the drupal node and try to save again (EVEN THO NO CHANGE IS MADE) the form no longer shows up and nothing shows up where it should be in the drupal page.

What could be causing this, poorly written PHP? I'm sure there's no virus.

Comment: It might be helpful to describe the virus detection method, how you are saving the content etc.

Comment: Have you installed any extensions recently? Or it could be a posible hack attempt. I had this with Zen Cart, AVG detected viruses when my website was comprimised.

Comment: here is what i did. 1. the form was visible and appeared fine, 2. i went into the drupal page an copied the php, i saved to simple txt, php from dreamweaver, html from dreamweaver, notepad++, they all detected viruses.

Comment: what's strange is even if i edit the node and save right away without making any changes, the form still goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to reply directly to your question, so I'm putting it in an answer.

> If I open to edit the drupal node and try to save again (EVEN THO NO CHANGE IS MADE) the form no longer shows up and nothing shows up where it should be in the drupal page.

It is possible that you are not saving in PHP format, or do not have access to.  The default formats are usually *Plain Text*, *Filtered HTML*, or *Full HTML* and it is discouraged to give inline PHP code processing privileges to users.  So for the second part of your question, I'd check that.